# All dots(.) in Wordpress Permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How do you allow dots(.) in WordPress permalinks, I'm assuming it's a function I'll need to overwrite but have no idea how to achieve this.

It currently replaces a . with a -

I have a custom post type for stores such as apple and want the permalink to be [url]/apple.com for the stores.

How can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: A working solution to this has already been provided on:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119069/allow-dot-in-wordpress-permalinks-only-for-categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 

remove_filter('sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes');
function sanitize_title_with_dots_and_dashes($title) {
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        // Preserve escaped octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
        // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
        $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
        // Restore octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);
        $title = remove_accents($title);
        if (seems_utf8($title)) {
                if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                        $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
                }
                $title = utf8_uri_encode($title);
        }
        $title = strtolower($title);
        $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
        $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 ._-]/', '', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
        $title = trim($title, '-');
        $title = str_replace('-.-', '.', $title);
        $title = str_replace('-.', '.', $title);
        $title = str_replace('.-', '.', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('|([^.])\.$|', '$1', $title);
        $title = trim($title, '-'); // yes, again
        return $title;
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dots_and_dashes'); ?>
```

Should  work

Comment: You can put it in the  functions.php  of your activated theme

Comment: Thank you, I solved (.) problem but the post is giving me 404 not fount error after editing the permalink. Do you have any idea about that?